# I need to find out how I can search Japanese text using Full-Text search in SQL Server 2014 or later

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, cjk

I think this may be a known difficulty but am looking for any suggestions, experience or work arounds that anyone may have.

I have a mature SQL Server 2014 database where all character columns are nvarchar. My application is a WPF application .NET 4.6-+ and it comfortably writes and reads text in any language so all is good from that point. I use MS Full-Text search to search text in nvarchar(max) columns and this works perfectly with nearly all languages and I understand how this works behind the scenes. That is until I recently needed to search for Japanese text which does not work.

I am struggling to find sufficient information on this issue but I have worked out that the issues may well be to do with word boundaries which Japanese text does not seem to have much of. It looks like it stores most of its text in one big long string and joins what we know as words, which I can see why SQL Server will struggle with. I have tried ‘”*text to find*”’ wildcards with CONTAINS/CONTAINSTABLE but this still does not really work. Using LIKE is an option but with a possibly 20,000,000 rows that is out of the question.

I have been working with SQL Server for some time and know it very well, especially from a performance tuning point of view so I am certainly not new to it. Has anyone else come up against this and have you fond a solution to this? Surely SQL Server cannot simply rule Japan out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/choose-a-language-when-creating-a-full-text-index?view=sql-server-ver15#non-western-languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the Microsoft implementation of the fulltext search is that it allows, essentially, only [one language per fulltext index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql), and that language needs to be specified in the index definition if it differs from the default language of the SQL Server instance. Another limitation is that you can have only one fulltext index per table or indexed view.

There are several workarounds, depending on the architecture and complexity of your system. For example, you can create several tables, one per language, which will store the indexed content. Unfortunately, your application needs to somehow "understand" which record goes where, or it will be your users who will have to set the correct language every time they enter new data.

Alternatively, all the text can be stored in the same table, but instead you would create several indexed views, each exposing only a subset or records with the same language, and then create fulltext indices on these views. Again, the problem of language identification  still stands.

Of course, your application can try to detect the current keyboard layout as the user enters the text (not sure if it's possible in WPF, but I did that in WinForms). That will probably not work with copy-paste and uploaded documents, if your system stores any.

The most viable solution, in my experience, is to allow your customers to specify the FTS language themselves when they install your application. If your audience is global, you can't possibly cover every language out of the box. Thankfully, from what I've seen, English text is sought more or less reliably, regardless of the index language.

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt response Roger. Your answer has pointed me to some thing s I did not know and am currently finding out. WPF is an irrelevance as I simply run stored procedures that insert text in the full-text column which is then indexed. I didn’t know that you can create language specific full text indexes. The text that goes into these columns can be in any language and I can easily detect what language it is. So, you are suggesting that we can create an alternative table for Japanese? This would be really easy.

Comment: I installed the Japanese language and then created a full-text catalog using language 1041 (Japanese). I added some text in Japanese and it actually works. Thank you so much... All I need to do is create a separate catalog and direct the Japanese text to this. Easy.